Laravel 8.83.18 how to insert a model object into DB as epoch
I have in the db table named gos_matches with field created_at set as INT(10), so that I can insert into it value strtotime('now') as a value. However, I am getting the following error, when I use this web method from Laravel, to insert a row into the DB:
"message": "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `gos_matches` (`gos_match_uid`, `initiator`, `performer`, `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (8bb42e75-be0e-4aeb-9ccb-57d6394f2ab3, despo2, despo3, despo2, 2024-08-24 16:30:29, 2024-08-24 16:30:29))",

I really want to have the epoch time in DB , just as I have it on the frontend side, so, please advise? What is the correct way to set this field in the DB, but keeping it as 10 digit epoch time?
